# Calling method with variable arguments from JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, variadic-functions

In a backing bean I declared following method

```
public boolean hasPermission(Object... objects) {
...
}
```

And I'm trying to call it from JSF 2.0 as follows:

```
<c:set var="hasPermission" scope="view" value="#{restrictions.hasPermission(entity)}" />
```

And it throws

```
javax.el.ELException:  Cannot convert Entity of class com.testing.Entity to class [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

If I pass two arguments, then it throws

```
Method hasPermission not found
```

Can I somehow call varargs methods from JSF 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varargs is not officially supported in EL. At least, it's nowhere specified in [EL specification.](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html) There does also not seem to be any plans to introduce it in the upcoming [EL 3.0](http://java.net/projects/el-spec).

You need to look for a different solution. As the functional requirement is unclear, I can't suggest any one.

---

**Update** it seems that the Apache EL parser as supplied in Tomcat supports this. It at least isn't supported by Sun/Oracle EL parser as supplied in Glassfish.

Answer (score 2):

On Tomcat 7 JSF 2.1.4 following works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="click 1"
        action="#{test.var('a','b',1,test.i,test.d,test.s,test.ss)}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="click 2"
        action="#{test.var('a','b',1)}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="click 3"
        action="#{test.var(test.i,test.d,test.s,test.ss)}"/>
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class Test {

    private Integer i = 10;
    private Double d = 10.0;
    private String s = "varargs";
    private String[] ss = new String[]{"1","2","3"};
    public Integer getI() {
        return i;
    }
    public void setI(Integer i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
    public Double getD() {
        return d;
    }
    public void setD(Double d) {
        this.d = d;
    }
    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }
    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
    public String[] getSs() {
        return ss;
    }
    public void setSs(String[] ss) {
        this.ss = ss;
    }

    public void var(Object...objects){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(objects));
    }
}
```

Output : on click 1,2,3

> [a, b, 1, 10, 10.0, varargs, [Ljava.lang.String;@4fa9cba5]
>
> [a, b, 1]
>
> [10, 10.0, varargs, [Ljava.lang.String;@26b923ee]

Is this what you are looking for.... as the way you are trying to call in question is blank.

Comment: Interesting. That must be Tomcat specific. It fails in Glassfish. It's at least nowhere specified in EL specification that varargs must be supported.

Comment: @BalusC not an active glassfish user, but good to know of its support in glassfish.

Comment: Hi
how can I use this in outputText
---
`<h:outputText value="#{testBean.findTotalLengthStr('1123','123','421')}" /> 
---
testBean
 public int findTotalLength(String ... strArray) {
  int totalLength = 0;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
   totalLength = totalLength + strArray[i].length();
  }

  return totalLength;
 }

`